# Rails 3 link or button that executes action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, rails-routing

In RoR 3, I just want to have a link/button that activates some action/method in the controller.  Specifically, if I click on a 'update_specs' link on a page, it should go to 'update_specs' method in my products controller.  I've found suggestions to do this on this site:

```
link_to "Update Specs", :controller => :products, :action => :update_specs
```

However, I get the following routing error when I click on this link:

> Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"update_specs",
>   :controller=>"products"}

I've read up on routing but I don't understand why I should have to route this method if all other methods are accessible via resources:products.

Comment: You need to route this method, because your action isn't accessible through standard REST routes generated with `resources` generator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a route for it.

For instance:

```
resources :products do
  put :update_specs, :on => :collection
end
```

Also by default `link_to` will look for a `GET` method in your routes. If you want to handle a `POST` or `PUT` method you need to specify it by adding `{:method => :post }` or  `{:method => :put }` as a parameter, like:

```
link_to "Update Specs", {:controller => :products, :action => :update_specs}, {:method => :put }
```

Or you can use `button_to` instead of `link_to` which handles the `POST` method by default.