# link_to :controller, :action in view not working ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, routes, link-to

Trying to use link_to to send info to action in my controller.

Link looks like this:

```
<%= link_to "Buy", {:controller => :policies, :action => :policy_option_price_calc, :option => "policy_option_a_cost" }, {:method => :post}  %>
```

I have a policies controller and inside my action looks like this:

```
def policy_option_price_calc(params)
   #logic stuff

   render :partial => "/policies/swipe_protect/price_total"
end
```

and in my routes I have:

```
resources :policies
    member do
        post 'policy_option_price_calc'
    end
end
```

I don't know why but I am getting this url when clicking the link_to link:

```
http://localhost:3000/?action=policy_option_price_calc&controller=policies&option=policy_option_a_cost
```

Which of course doesn't exist, but its not even giving me an error its just being processed by my `HomeControll#index`

I have looked at:

[Form tag helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag)

[rubyguild routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

[Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558601/rails-3-link-or-button-that-executes-action-in-controller)

Plus many more. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the named route format?

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', policy_option_price_calc_policy_url(:option => 'policy_option_a_cost'), :method => :post %>
```

You may have to tweak the name of the route, but that's what I would do.  The way you're trying to do it you would want to use strings instead of symbols:

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', { :controller => 'policies', :action => 'policy_option_price_calc', :option => 'policy_option_a_cost' }, { :method => :post } %>
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string for more information.

Comment: I have tried using strings, actually that was the first thing that I tired. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the

```
{ :method => post }
```

hash I think the expected url will be created.
At the moment your request is routed to the HomeController because that is what your URL is invoking.

```
http://localhost:3000/policies/?action=policy_option_price_calc&controller=policies&option=policy_option_a_cost
```

is the route you are thinking about, but the **policies/** part is missing.

However this is **not the solution to your problem.** For a POST request you should use button_to or form helper instead of link_to.