# Accessing a method in rails controller via button/link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to follow the solution on this thread - [Rails 3 link or button that executes action in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558601/rails-3-link-or-button-that-executes-action-in-controller)

I defined :update_question in my routes.rb file:

```
  resources :surveys do
    put :update_question, :on => :member
  end
```

and in my controller:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_question

  # GET /surveys
  # GET /surveys.json
  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  # GET /surveys/1
  # GET /surveys/1.json
  def show
  end

  def survey
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  end

  # GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  # GET /surveys/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def update_question
    flash[:alert] = "getting there man"
  end
```

And listed the link here in the html:

```
<%= link_to "Next Question", update_question_survey_path(@survey), {:method => :put} %>
```

However when I click the link I get this error:

```
Template is missing
Missing template surveys/update_question, application/update_question with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.
```

Which seems to elude that it's looking for a view - but really I just want it to run the method in my survey controller and update the question that's being displayed. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, any help/suggestions is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the action is correctly reached, but then Rails tries to render something. By default, it will look for a view file with the same name of the action.

You should do something like this:

```
def update_question
  set_survey
  # do stuff
  flash[:alert] = "getting there man"
  redirect_to survey_path(@survey)
end
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes total sense - and I can just set my new params to display the new question.